# Using a scipt to Switch between 2 wifi networks using two different network cards

Tags: wireless, bash, iwlwifi

I need to switch between **2 different networks** where one has internet (**metered using internet over a cellular service**) and the other doesn't have internet.

Does someone know how / have a script that will run when I click on the icon I can swap between the two networks.  It can be two separate icons.

**Example:**

I have **two** wifi cards in a laptop an internal **intel wifi** and a **USB external wifi. (connects to the internet using Metered Cell Service)**

Click the **1st icon** with the script to connect to the wifi network with **no internet** using the **intel wifi network card** and **disables the USB external wifi Card**

Click the **2nd icon** with script to connect to wifi network **with internet** using the **USB external wifi card** and **disables the internal intel wifi card**

Comment: What is preventing you from leaving the second network card on all the time for local resources, and toggling the Internet-connected network only when needed? 

Comment: @matigo I've noticed when both cards are on the routing sometimes seems to get confused (it tries to route information out both network cards at the same time)  but if you have a script I can try I'll give it a shot again.

Comment: @RickT did you find a script solution for this?  I have a very similar situation that I would like a script for.  I also have an external USB wireless and a internal wireless.  I don't want them running at the same time.

Comment: Nothing that worked well...The nic's always tried to step on each other.